# Stop the execution of FormClosing event at specific condition?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I made multi languages c# application that will switch the language

1. when user change Language  the application must restart in order for the application change the language

now I have one question and one problem

1. Is there away to change the language without restarting the application ?
2. a problem showup when `Application.Restart();` executed the `Formclosing` event raised too as shown below and as result the application will not restart 
   and will promet for the exit message and close if `Yes` and will a lanche another copy of the application with new language without closing the old one 
   now.. Is there away the so the `Formclosing` event not executed in that case only ? or better to have away as I mentioned ad point 1 above.

   ```
   private void F0100_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
   {
       DialogResult result;

       result = MessageBox.Show("Are sure you want to exit?", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2, MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading);
       if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
       {
           Environment.Exit(1);
       }
       else
       { e.Cancel = true; }
   }
   ```

Comment: try the update panel it may resolve your probleme

Comment: @AmineRamoul please I searched and found all example are explained in asp.net can I use it with c# windows form application ? tutorial youtube links are really appreciated ..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is just to avoid giving the user the possibility to stop the closing when you execute the call to Application.Restart, then all you need to do is to look at the CloseReason passed to your Form_Closing event handler

```
private void F0100_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    // Do not prompt the user if we have called Application.Restart
    if(e.CloseReason != CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall)
    {
        DialogResult result;
        ....
    }
}
```